# Spring config server security encryption and decryption not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, cryptography, spring-cloud-config

I am using spring config server and spring security. I have followed the link 
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html
I have added JCF in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\security folder.
When I post localhost:8080/encrypt
{
    "description": "The encryption algorithm is not strong enough",
    "status": "INVALID"
}
This response comes. Please let me know the issue.

Comment: Did you exactly follow the link? If not, put some parameters that you used.

Answer (score 16):

if you are getting **{"description": "The encryption algorithm is not strong enough", "status": "INVALID" }** response.The **solution** is just create bootstrap.properties file in config server and add encrypt.key="Secrete Key" property.

Answer (score 8):

Disclaimer: I am running *org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server:2.0.6.RELEASE*.

It's not just enought to enable unlimited crypto policy (btw, it is by default starting from ***jdk8.161***), but you have to also provide (in case you want to use symmetric cryptography) *encrypt.key* property.

You can find it down the documentation: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/2.0.x/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_key_management

PS: Set it within ***bootstrap.properties***.

Answer (score 5):

With spring cloud config server 2, we get an error response for endpoint /encrypt as The encryption algorithm is not strong enough.
This error occurs if you don't have encrypt.key property defined. **Even if this is defined, to avoid this error, the property `encrypt.key` should be placed in `bootstrap.properties` rather than `application.properties`.**

Answer (score 3):

`bootstrap.properties` are meant to be tracked under source control so i would rather reference the `envcrypt.key` value as an operating system environment variable.

For unix systems use `export ENCRYPT_KEY=YOURKEY`

Add this variable to one of start up files `~/bashrc, ~.profile or ~/.login` to make it permanent

Answer (score 2):

The cloud config server's `encrypt.key` property is used to decrypt encrypted properties in the configuration files therefore it is clearly too late (and wrong from a security perspective) to provide said key in those configuration files.

It needs to be available to the bootstrap context so yes you can put it in `bootstrap.yml` if that configuration file is suitably secured or better yet it should be provided at startup time by a trusted secret storage system like Vault.

It's a shame that Spring's way of telling you that you have got this wrong is to emit this error message:

```
{"description":"The encryption algorithm is not strong enough","status":"INVALID"}
```